# PageReference: Redirect to built page

Tags: apex, json, pagereference, xml

Can I build some XML or JSON in Apex and then redirect to it from a method that returns a PageReference object?

```
public PageReference saveText() {
    PageReference p = new PageReference(someJSONObject);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: you can try using metadata api to create/save a page from the json and then redirect to the page you just saved.

Comment: Got any documentation on it handy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a PageReference isn't content, it's just a reference to some content, which Visualforce then redirects the user to.  You could render your json in a Visualforce page and specify the mime type, for example:

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" contentType="application/json" 
           controller="jsonTestController">
  {!jsonText}
</apex:page>
```

However, if you need to return JSON or XML in this manner, you would probably be better off using [Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_intro.htm) to write a class that handles HTTP requests & responses directly, without invoking Visualforce.  And since Apex REST exposes your class at a public URL, you can always return a PageReference to the URL from your controller if you have a use case that does require redirecting from a VF page to an API end point.

Comment: Yeah, I explored that, but the lack of auth. options with my other app limit my options severely.

Comment: Hold up, what about this? http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/anything-worth-doing/a-better-way-to-generate-xml-on-salesforce-using-visualforce-55433

Comment: Looks like they are doing what I showed in my example- generating the actual output via Visualforce.  The page reference they return (`PageReference aPage = Page.AccountContactsXML;`) is a reference to the Visualforce page named "AccountContactsXML", which iterates through the controller data to output xml.  Note the use of `contentType` in the vf `page` tag to specify mime type.